# App updates not listed in apt list --upgradeable

Tags: apt

I am an amateur Ubuntu user and recently I've noticed two things:

- whenever I open DBeaver, it prompts me to install a new minor version; when I click the button, I get redirected to the DBeaver website and need to manually download the new update
- `apt list --upgradeable` does not list DBeaver updates

I installed DBeaver via Ubuntu "Software" utility, my OS: Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS x86_64, kernel: 4.15.0-50-generic.

Is it possible to configure an app to be updateable via `sudo apt update` along with other updates, if it's not by default?

[image]

Comment: `apt update` updates your software repository lists, but does not actually upgrade your software. `apt upgrade` (and `apt full-upgrade`) do that.  apt & dpkg tools work for the software repository lists found in `/etc/apt/sources.list` and those found in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/` so if it is setup to use as a list, has key etc then you could add it to a new entry in the sources.list.d/ subdirectory and have apt/dpkg tools manage it. But it is in a signed repository?

Comment: I'm unable to found any dbeaver from Ubuntu Software, maybe you installed it within snap ?

Comment: @Jim I have updated my question with screenshot from the Software

Comment: @guiverc it isn't in the mentioned file nor directory. So I should probably reinstall it via `apt` if its possible, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The screenshot in your question shows that you have the dbeaver-ce snap package installed. Packages that were installed by apt and snap packages are upgraded by two different commands from the terminal. `apt list --upgradeable` shows only the upgradeable packages that were installed by `apt`. To upgrade all snap packages run `sudo snap refresh`

Software Updater also only updates installed apt packages. Installed snap packages are automatically updated separately in the background. If there are snap packages that require authentication in order to be upgraded the Software app shows a notification that updates for snap package(s) are available. Clicking the notification opens the Software app with a small authentication window in front of it.